# Send email using php ,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

I need to send an email to user to notify them of reports expiring.

Code I have set up so far but it is not sending the email nor are there any error messages through the browser, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'connect_mobile.php'; 
/*
$today = $_POST['reportdate'];
$name = $_POST['engineername'];
$engineerid = $_POST['engineerid'];
$engineeremail = $_POST['engineeremail'];
*/
$today = '2013-03-14';
$name = 'John Wheeler';
$engineerid = '130';
$engineeremail = 'jwheating@gmail.com';


$to = $engineeremail;
$subject = "Report expiring 30 days";

// give your message the starting string
$message = 'Greetings '.$name.',

    you are receiving this email as a reminder that the following reports expire in 30  days:
    <table style="width: 80%;">
        <tr>
            <td>Report No</td>
            <td>Client</td>
            <td>Property Address</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Postcode</td>
            <td>Expiry Date</td>
        </tr>
'
$query = "SELECT * FROM certifs WHERE currentdate = '"$today"' AND userid = '"$engineerid"'"
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $message .= "        <tr>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['certno']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['clientcompany']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd1']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd2']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd3']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertypostcode']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['currentdate']."</td>";
    $message .= "        </tr>";

    // then update the message with the ending
    $message .= "
    </table>

    Thank you,
    John Wheeler Gas Reports."

}
//-- The headers will let us send HTML code as an email
$headers = "From: support@john-wheeler.co.uk\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


//-- if mail gets sent, return true, else return false.
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
$response = array('mail' => true);
}
else
{
$response = array('mail' => false);
}

echo json_encode($response);

}
?>
```

HI, thank you all for pointing out my silly mistakes, I corrected the syntax now at least I get an error message.

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for 'user'johnny'@'localhost' (using password:NO) in /var/www/vhosts/vvps-835282.dailyvps.co.uk/john-wheeler.co.uk/mobilereports/reportexpires.php on line 35 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/vhosts/vvps-835282.dailyvps.co.uk/john-wheeler.co.uk/mobilereports/reportexpires.php on line 35 Access denied for user 'johnny'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How the hell do I format code? Sorry first time on StackOverflow.

The code is on my VPS, I have other mail scripts running fine using mail.

Comment: If you output `$to`, `$subject`, `$message` and `$headers` to the screen, what are they?

Comment: Do you have a mail server set up somewhere?

Comment: try setup a page that just calls the mail() function to check that the server is set up correctly.

Comment: you should check the apache error log if you are getting a blank screen. cause this code MUST output something, if not, then there is a fatal error preventing the output.

Comment: Your error message reflects an inability to connect to the database. Please include your code that connects to the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = 'Greetings '.$name.',

    you are receiving this email as a reminder that the following reports expire in 30  days:
    <table style="width: 80%;">
        <tr>
            <td>Report No</td>
            <td>Client</td>
            <td>Property Address</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Postcode</td>
            <td>Expiry Date</td>
        </tr>
'
```

You're missing a `;` at the end of this. You aren't getting any error messages as it's a syntax error.

**and** at the end of this line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM certifs WHERE currentdate = $today AND userid = $engineerid"
```

Comment: HI, thanks corrected the syntax now at least I get an error message.
   
    Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user'johnny'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/vhosts/vvps-835282.dailyvps.co.uk/john-wheeler.co.uk/mobilereports/reportexpires.php on line 35 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /var/www/vhosts/vvps-835282.dailyvps.co.uk/john-wheeler.co.uk/mobilereports/reportexpires.php on line 35 Access denied for user 'johnny'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Comment: You aren't logging into your MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have some errors in

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM certifs WHERE currentdate = '"$today"' AND userid = '"$engineerid"'"
                                                  ....^
```

Missed to add `;` in some places, I have corrected the same and  use below one,

Replace:

```
    // give your message the starting string
    $message = 'Greetings '.$name.',

        you are receiving this email as a reminder that the following reports expire in 30  days:
        <table style="width: 80%;">
            <tr>
                <td>Report No</td>
                <td>Client</td>
                <td>Property Address</td>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td>Postcode</td>
                <td>Expiry Date</td>
            </tr>
    ';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM certifs WHERE currentdate = '$today' AND userid = '$engineerid'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $message .= "        <tr>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['certno']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['clientcompany']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd1']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd2']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd3']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertypostcode']."</td>";
        $message .= "            <td>".$row['currentdate']."</td>";
        $message .= "        </tr>";

        // then update the message with the ending
        $message .= "
        </table>

        Thank you,
        John Wheeler Gas Reports.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'connect_mobile.php'; 
/*
$today = $_POST['reportdate'];
$name = $_POST['engineername'];
$engineerid = $_POST['engineerid'];
$engineeremail = $_POST['engineeremail'];
*/
$today = '2013-03-14';
$name = 'John Wheeler';
$engineerid = '130';
$engineeremail = 'jwheating@gmail.com';


$to = $engineeremail;
$subject = "Report expiring 30 days";

// give your message the starting string
$message = 'Greetings '.$name.',
    you are receiving this email as a reminder that the following reports expire in 30  days:
    <table style="width: 80%;">
        <tr>
            <td>Report No</td>
            <td>Client</td>
            <td>Property Address</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>Postcode</td>
            <td>Expiry Date</td>
        </tr>
';
$query = "SELECT * FROM certifs WHERE currentdate = '".$today."' AND userid = '".$engineerid."'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $message .= "        <tr>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['certno']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['clientcompany']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd1']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd2']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertyadd3']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['propertypostcode']."</td>";
    $message .= "            <td>".$row['currentdate']."</td>";
    $message .= "        </tr>";

    // then update the message with the ending
    $message .= "
    </table>

    Thank you,
    John Wheeler Gas Reports.";

}
//-- The headers will let us send HTML code as an email
$headers = "From: support@john-wheeler.co.uk\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


//-- if mail gets sent, return true, else return false.
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
$response = array('mail' => true);
}
else
{
$response = array('mail' => false);
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

you have a lot of syntax problems... maybe but that.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a mail server setup then add this to your php.ini file

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

for Linux/Unix systems